# Track servers from different GEO locations using Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have one web site which have main domain let's say example.com. The same web site hosted on three web servers in different data-centers across globe - USA, Europe and Asia. The web site and Google Analytic code are identical on all servers. I would like to track web servers in Analytic to know from which server user get server a web site. Should I create three different Analytic sites and use different Analytics code in every server? What I don't like about this idea that I will not see all users stats because it will be separated in three Analytics profiles.

Could you please suggest better solution for my problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the "Network domain" as a secondary dimension? If that helps, then you could create views specifically for those network domains.

Comment: I just done it and that's what I needed, now I have several views with different locations filtered by server name and one main view with all Analytics data in it! Thank you for suggestion! You could post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the secondary dimension of "Network Domain" so that you can filter off of that in your views.